# Using attrs (Attribute List) in <xp:viewColumn>

Tags: xpages

I am trying to use the `attrs` inside `<xp:viewColumn>`. Below is a small snippet from my code.

```
<xp:viewPanel rows="5" id="viewPanel1" var="rowDocument">
  <xp:this.facets>
    <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1"></xp:pager>
  </xp:this.facets>
  <xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="MyView"></xp:dominoView>
  </xp:this.data>
  <xp:viewColumn columnName="$22" id="viewColumn1">
    <xp:this.attrs>
      <xp:attr name="draggable" value="true"></xp:attr>
      <xp:attr name="onDragStart">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[dragIt(event, "SOME VALUE");]]></xp:this.value>
      </xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>
    <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Name" id="viewColumnHeader1"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
  </xp:viewColumn>
</xp:viewPanel>
```

Basically I am adding the `draggable` attribute to use drag and drop functionality. But the generated HTML does not add this attribute to the `<td>` or the `<span>` tags generated for the view data. My generated HTML looks like this:

```
<table id="view:_id1:viewPanel1" class="xspDataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">
        <div class="xspPanelViewColumnHeader"><span><span id="view:_id1:viewPanel1:viewColumn1:__internal_header_title_id" class="xspPanelViewColumnHeader">Name</span></span></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="xspColumnViewEnd"><span id="view:_id1:viewPanel1:0:viewColumn1:_internalViewText" class="xspTextViewColumn">Data 1</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xspColumnViewEnd"><span id="view:_id1:viewPanel1:1:viewColumn1:_internalViewText" class="xspTextViewColumn">Data 2</span></td>
    </tr>
    ..........
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Why it is not adding the attribute to the individual row data? Is there any other way I can do that?

**UPDATE:** If I add `attrs` to `<xp:viewColumnHeader>` then generated HTML code displays the additional attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more (or total) control on the generated output, you're probably better of using a repeat control instead of a viewPanel:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="view2" viewName="MyView"></xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>

<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="5" value="#{view2}" var="viewRow">

    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:text xp:key="header" disableTheme="true" escape="false">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[<table><tbody>]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
        <xp:text xp:key="footer" disableTheme="true" escape="false">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[</tbody></table>]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
    </xp:this.facets>

    <tr>
        <xp:text escape="false" tagName="td" value="#{viewRow.$22}">
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="draggable" value="true"></xp:attr>
                <xp:attr name="onDragStart">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[dragIt(event, "SOME VALUE");]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>
        </xp:text>
    </tr>

</xp:repeat>
```

Comment: Repeat was my last option, mainly because I will have to create everything myself their (just like your code snippet). So is there no way to make this work in `<xp:viewColumn>`? If yes then why is there a property of `attrs` in `<xp:viewColumn>`? Is it a bug?